# Sign Up and Sign In with 'Terms of Use' prompt - Internal Error Server

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've been debugging this internal server error using application insights it's been hours now and I believe it's time to ask for help. My custom policy is been enhanced with 'Terms of Use' consent and my goal is simply to adapt the [existing sample on it](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) to my policy scenario. Easier said than done!

The error happens after the `"SelfAsserted-Input-ToU-SignIn"` technical profile is called, which is, at the Sign-In with `extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime` being prior to the date configured at `IsTermsOfUseConsentRequiredForDateTime`.

Here is a piece of the user journey:

```xml
...
 <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
          <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>
  
          <OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="Check-TOU-Status" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Check-TOU-Status" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>

         <!-- Display Terms of Use consent page for any SignIn scenario based on termsOfUseConsentRequired claim -->
         <OrchestrationStep Order="10" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <!-- Add condition to not execute this step for sign up scenario based on newUser claim -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>termsOfUseConsentRequired</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ShowToUConsentPageForNewUser" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Input-ToU-SignIn" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>   

        <OrchestrationStep Order="11" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <!-- Add condition to not execute this step for sign up scenario based on newUser claim -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTAuthB2CSignIn" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-AuthB2CSignIn" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
...
```

Application Insights does not show anything meaningful to me. No exceptions, no missing claims, etc., and the error message from the browser inner HTML doesn't help much as well, here one can see part of it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
--
  | <!-- Build: 1.0.2493.0 -->
  | <!-- StateVersion: 2.1.1 -->
  | <!-- DeploymentMode: Development -->
  | <!-- CorrelationId: ea9e5f4d-7e67-4253-8b1b-3f9ef32e43aa -->
  | <!-- DataCenter: SAN -->
  | <!-- Slice: 001-000 -->
  | <html lang="en-US"><head><link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="><script data-container="true" nonce="uckM+NtdqgKmNou1EkScIg==">var GLOBALEX = {
  | "CorrelationId": "ea9e5f4d-7e67-4253-8b1b-3f9ef32e43aa",
  | "Timestamp": "2022-02-08 18:59:26Z",
  | "Detail": "AADB2C: An exception has occurred."
  | };
  |  
  |  
  | var CONTENT = {
  | "contact-none": "Your administrator hasn&#39;t provided any contact details.",
  | "contact-number-label": "Telephone",
  | "contact-email-label": "Email",
  | "error-title": "Sorry, but we&#39;re having trouble signing you in.",
  | "error-help": "We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again."
  | };
```

---

What might be happening here?

All the involved policies + a full log file from application insights from the user journey can be found [here](https://github.com/RaphaelSilv/toc-policy).

Really appreciate your input on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was missing output claims on the `Update-TOU-Status` technical profile.

```xml
<OutputClaims>
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="termsOfUseConsentRequired" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
</OutputClaims>
```